# Import events(datas) in NEsper engine

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper, nesper

can anyone tell me how to import the events(datas) in NEsper engine to analyse whether pattern is catched or not?
I've already set and defined the pattern I want to catch and the event types(event class) and configured the runtime engine. Now I want to import my datas in the engine to analyse.
Is there any interface oder rest API or something provided by NEsper I can use to import data in CEP NEsper engine?
how can I do it?
thanks for any help!

Best regards, Narsu

Answer (score 0):

I seems covered in the ["Getting Started text"](http://esper.espertech.com/release-8.6.0/reference-esper/html_single/index.html#gettingstarted_runtimesteps_4).
It is just `runtime.getEventService().sendEvent...(...)`
Also check the examples

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. What I mean is, I have a live continuious data stream produced. I want to put all the continuious data stream into the CEP NEsper Engine. Is there any interface or API to do that?